# Disable One Point on Touchscreen

Tags: drivers, touchscreen, microsoft-surface, touch

Is there any software / drivers I am able to install which allow one pixel or an area of the screen to become 'touchscreen dead'? I have a 'phantom touch' problem on my Microsoft Surface Pro 4 where it thinks that I am constantly pressing one point on the screen when I am not. If I could just turn off that point and have the rest of the touchscreen work that would fix the whole issue. Anyone have anything similar happen or know any solutions?

Comment: Can you disable the touch screen until you can get it replaced?  Use a BlueTooth Mouse.

Comment: @John - How does the author disable the touchscreen, If the touchscreen, is malfunctioning and preventing that by phantom inputs?

Comment: The touchscreen is still semi usable a lot of programs just look at the most recent touch and I have a mouse. I would like to have the touchscreen be usable though as it is a tablet computer and it is far less portable as a laptop. That's why if I disable just the area where the phantom click keeps getting triggered then the screen shouldn't have any other problems.

Comment: If there is no way to disable the touchscreen (I was not sure) then you need to replace the screen.